# Using Jasmine to test a module calling another module

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I'm trying to use Jasmine to test that some modular JavaScript is initiating as expected. But I'm going round in circles.

As a simplified example, I have these two files:

```
// myObj.all.js
;(function() {
    window.myObj = window.myObj || {};

    myObj.all = {
        init: function() {
            myObj.page.init();
        }
    };
}());

// myObj.page.js
;(function() {
    window.myObj = window.myObj || {};

    myObj.page = {
        init: function() {
            console.log('hello');
        }
    };
}());
```

And in the HTML I would call:

```
myObj.all.init();
```

to initialise everything. There are more modules in addition to `myObj.page`, and one call to `myObj.all.init()` initialises all of them.

I want to test that when `myObj.all.init()` is called, then `myObj.page.init()` is also called. I thought something like this would do it, but the test fails:

```
spyOn(myObj.page, 'init');
myObj.all.init({});
expect(myObj.page.init).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

How should I test this?

Answer (score 0):

I have never used jasmine but an easy way to verify that methods are being called from within another method is to [mock](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2014/03/27/mocks-in-jasmine-tests) the methods that should be called.

It looks like jasmine has support for [mocking](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2014/03/27/mocks-in-jasmine-tests).

In this case you could mock `myObj.page.init()` and all other methods that should be called from `myObj.all.init()`.  The mocking should provide a method to assert that the mocked method was actually called.